# JQuery: elegant way to replace set of elements with another set?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a bunch of DOM like

```
<div>
    <div class="stuff"/>
    <div class="stuff"/>
    <div class="stuff"/>
</div>
```

and I want to replace it with a new set of stuff

```
<div>
    <div class="stuff"/>
    <p class="stuff"/>
    <ul class="stuff"/>
    <a class="stuff"/>
</div>
```

Which will be fetched via Ajax. My question is: what is the best way to do this?

`$.replaceWith` doesn't quite do what I want, because I then end up with multiple copies of the new `stuff`.

I can guarantee that all the `stuff` will be in one contiguous block, and so presumably I could put in some placeholder after the last element (or before the first element) of the old `stuff`, remove the old `stuff`, and replace the placeholder with the new `stuff`.

However, this seems rather roundabout and inelegant. Is there any clever way of, removing all the old `stuff` and putting in a single copy of the new `stuff`, all at one go?

EDIT: I would also like to do this without using any container divs. Using container divs would work in the above case, but would fail in some cases, like when the `stuff` is inside a `<table>`:

```
<table>
    <head/>
    <body>
        <tr/>
        <tr class="stuff"/>
        <tr class="stuff"/>
        <tr class="stuff"/>
        <tr/>
    </body>
</table>
```

If i want to replace the rows labelled `stuff` with another set of rows, possibly more, possibly fewer, there is no way I can nicely put them in a container thingy without breaking the HTML, since the `<body>` can only contain `<tr>`s (IIRC).

Comment: What have you tried that isn't elegant? There are many ways to do this, which one did you try?

Comment: @thecodeparadox fixed the markup. Joseph: the whole insert-placeholder, remove old stuff, replace-placeholder thing

Comment: If the "stuff" is in a TABLE, then the TD or the TABLE *is* the container.

Comment: @Diodeus: sorry, the first example was bad, I changed it to expose the problem. Replacing some subset of the rows of a table with another set of rows, possibly a different number of them, is something I'm actually doing, so it's not just me being stubborn or picky.

Comment: @Diodeus the problem is preserving siblings.  My updated answer does that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$('#outerdiv').empty().append(newContent);
```

Unlike `.html()`, this will work regardless of whether `newContent` is an HTML string, or an existing DOM structure.

If there are multiple elements to be replaced but where you need to retain their siblings, you can do this:

```
$('.stuff').first().before(newContent).end().remove();
```

i.e. take the first `.stuff` element, add the new content before it, and then remove all the `.stuff` elements.

Comment: This seems to work, an I think it passes the "elegance" test. Thanks =)

Answer (score 4):

One way to do it would be with [`wrapAll`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/):

```
$('.stuff').wrapAll('<div/>').parent().replaceWith('<div class="stuff"/>');
```

I'm not sure if that passes the "elegant" test, but it does work regardless of whether there is any other content in the containing element.

With that said, though, this seems to be a very complicated solution to a simple problem. The simple solution would be to wrap your elements in a containing element; this shouldn't be a problem if, as you say, you can guarantee that they will always be together.

Answer (score 3):

Yes: `$('#tagetDiv').html(newContent)`

Comment: I should have put it down that I do not want to require any container div to do this. Having a container div/span works in most cases, but occasionally (annoyingly!) fails at the edges (container divs messing up CSS formatting, replacing the body/head/rows/cells of a table, etc).

Comment: @LiHaoyi if you don't have a container how are you supposed to know _which_ divs to replace?

Comment: @Alnitak: by their class `stuff`, which is shared by all the divs I want to yank out and replace

Comment: Then that would be: $('.stuff').parent()

Comment: @Diodeus except that `.stuff` may have siblings which should be left untouched...