# Way to replace a certain set of elements with another set?

Tags: jquery, html, replace

Before you mark this as a duplicate of [JQuery: elegant way to replace set of elements with another set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723452/jquery-elegant-way-to-replace-set-of-elements-with-another-set), please read my question.

The answers of the question which I mentioned above only allow the replacing of all the elements inside a certain parent selector with another set.

What I want is to replace a certain set, like for example `#foo1` and `#foo3` in the following example, but not `#foo2` and `#foo4`:

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="foo1">Foo1</div>
  <div id="foo2">Foo2</div>
  <div id="foo3">Foo3</div>
  <div id="foo4">Foo4</div>
</div>
```

Just say I wanted to replace the elements `#foo1` and `#foo3` with two divs with an id of `#foo5` and `#foo6`. I don't want to change any other elements.

Would this be remotely possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `replaceWith` method.

```
$('#foo1').replaceWith($('#foo5'))​
```

Or:

```
$('#foo1').replaceWith('<div id="foo5">Content</div>')​
```

Comment: What if I wanted to select, for example, `<span>fo</span><span>o</span>` and replace any occurrences of that with `<span>foo</span>`? Would that be possible?

Comment: @think123 Yes, it's possible, `$('span').replaceWith('<span>foo</span>')`

Comment: But what if I also had `<span>Otherfoo</span>` on my page, and I didn't want that replaced?

Comment: @think123 You can use not selector or filter method: `$('span:not(:contains(Otherfoo))').replaceWith()`

Comment: No offence, but that's not exactly a solution. I want to select those elements and those only. I'm not exactly sure of the other content on my page, as it is dynamic. I want to select those and those only.

Comment: @think123 There should be some hints for excluding some elements, I have suggested contains based on your example.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `replaceWith` method:

```
$('#foo1').replaceWith('<div id="foo5">Foo4</div>');​
```

Edit: bleh, too late, duplicate answer :P